# NGINX: reverse proxy path to subdomain and append the rest

Tags: nginx, regex, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following NGINX configuration file:

```
server {
  server_name devices.example.org;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/web/example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/web/example.key;

  location ~* ^/(.*)(.*)?$ {
    proxy_pass                  http://$1.proxy.tv$2;
    proxy_buffering             off;
    proxy_set_header Host       $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  }
```

And I need to proxy all incoming requests to the shown backend, i.e.

- `https://devices.example.org/m123` should proxy to `http://m123.proxy.tv`
- `https://devices.example.org/m123/favicon.ico` should proxy to `http://m123.proxy.tv/favicon.ico`
- `https://devices.example.org/m123/scripts/something.js?params=bar` should proxy to `http://m123.proxy.tv/scripts/something.js?params=bar`

However, I always get the a **Bad Gateway** error as a return, and in the logs I get:

```
[error] 18643#0: *12393 favicon.ico.proxy.tv could not be resolved (3: Host not found)
```

I assume that my regex somehow malforms the proxy request, but I'm not sure how.

Other combinations that I've tried:

- `location ~* ^/(.*)(?:/(.*))$` proxied to `http://$1.proxy.tv/$2$is_args$args`
- `location ~* ^/(.*)(?:/(.*))?` proxied to `http://$1.proxy.tv/$2$is_args$args`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two wildcard regular expression capture groups in your `location` block directive, which means everything is captured into `$1`.

Based on your requirements, the following `location` block could work:

```
location ~ ^/(?<subdomain>[^/]+)/(?<path>.*)?$ {
    proxy_pass http://$subdomain.proxy.tv/$path;
    ...
}
```

For clarity, I am using variable names (`<>`) in the regular expressions. The `[^/]+` is used to capture the first part of URL path component (capture 1 or more characters that are not `/`).

The reason for the `Bad Gateway` error is that nginx could not resolve the domain name `favicon.ico.proxy.tv`. These are couple of reasons why it happens:

1. `favicon.ico.proxy.tv` is not registered in DNS.
2. You haven't configured nginx `resolver` directive with valid DNS resolvers.

Comment: I am receiving an error that the "path" variable is unknown, do I need to define this somewhere beforehand?

Comment: My answer had an error, I have fixed it. The `?` was missing, which meant that capture to `$path` variable did not work.